# TYPO3: indexed_search and encoding

Tags: search, encoding, utf-8, typo3, iso-8859-1

I have a TYPO3 v. 4.3.2 and Indexed Search Engine 2.12.0. If I make a search I see a

Ã– instead of Ö
Ã¼ instead of ü

So it seems that utf8 characters are represented as ISO-8859-1. If I look into the source code I see

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In the TS setup there is also a

```
page.config.metaCharset = utf-8
page.config.additionalHeaders = Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
```

So it is a settings from the indexed search extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the database and Typo3 to uft-8. In Typo3 it is with the option forceCharset=utf-8 and setDBinit = set names utf-8 and set character set utf-8 in the installtool. To convert a mysql database to utf-8 at the command line type:

Dumped the original db with the following command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --opt --default-character-set=latin1 --skip-set-charset  DBNAME > DBNAME
```

Then using sed I changed all occurrences of the word latin1 to utf8:

```
sed -e 's/latin1/utf8/g' -i ./DBNAME.sql
```

From here I then created the new database and then imported the dumpfile.

```
mysql -p -e "create database DBNAME"
mysql -p --default-character-set=utf8  DBNAME < DBNAME.sql
```

Here is what the mysql manual wrote about alter table tbl_name CONVERT TO...

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

" If you want to change the table default character set and all character
columns (CHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT) to a new character set, use a statement like this:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

Warning

The preceding operation converts column values between the character sets.
This is not what you want if you have a column in one character set (like
latin1) but the stored values actually use some other, incompatible
character set (like utf8). In this case, you have to do the following for
each such column:

```
 ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 BLOB;
 ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE c1 c1 TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

The reason this works is that there is no conversion when you convert to or
from BLOB columns. "

If you need to convert the content you need to either dump it and use my method or use ALTER TABLE tbl_name CHANGE ... for each column.

Comment: But the other parts of the website are correctly displayed. Only indexed_search makes problems. `[forceCharset]` is `utf-8`, `[setDBinit]` is `set names utf8`, and I can't find a `set character set utf-8`. The collation of the tables is `utf8_unicode_ci`, but phpMyAdmin writes as summary of all tables `latin1_swedish_ci`. Perhaps that's the reason? Should I convert the database like this `ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8_unicode_ci;`?

Comment: OK, I also found out that this is true only for some pages. If I make a search with another key words everything is correctly displayed ...

Comment: @testing: I've expanded my answer to cover mysql database ISO-8859-1 to utf-8 conversion.

Comment: So I would need a shell access with the commands you mentioned. I don't know if this is possible. Does the `ALTER TABLE` not work? As I mentioned before only some pages are concerned from this effect.

Comment: @testing: Yes, think so. See my answer. ALTER TABLE Convert isn't converting the content of the column but only the column meta data.

Comment: I think the data is already in utf-8, because the tables and the data fields have `utf8_unicode_ci`. Additionally, in phpMyAdmin the data looks correct. Only `show variables like "collation_database";` gives me `latin1_swedish_ci`. So the meta description of the database is wrong? And why there are only some pages which are incorrectly displayed? Wouldn't be a possibility to clear some caches or try to reindex certain pages?

Comment: @testing: Trust me, collation is only for sorting. It didn't work for me so I suggest you to use my method and dump the table and reimport. There isn't another solution. Maybe the alter change.